# show/hide form elements on the basis of dropdown value

Tags: jquery

I have a requirement that I have a form in which some fields are mandatory and some are not.I have a drop down in my form having two condition first is "show all fields" and another is "show only mandatory fields" now what I want to do is that when user selects "show all fields" than all fields are shown and when user selects "show only mandatory fields" then only mandatory fields will be shown.

```
<form:form method="POST" action="addCountry.htm" commandName="countryForm" id="countryForm">
    <table>

    <tr>
        <td>Select fields:</td>
        <td align="center">
            <select name="fields">
                <option value="non mandatory">show all fields</option>
                <option value="mandatory">show only mandatory fields</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>Country Name :</td>
            <td><form:input path="countryName"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Country ISD Code  :</td>
            <td><form:textarea path="countryISDCode" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Nationality :</td>
            <td><form:textarea path="nationality"/></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td colspan="3"><input type="submit" value="submit"/></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form:form>
```

Take this form as a example in which country name and country ISD code is mandatory and nationality is not mandatory.Now on the basis of drop down selection I want to show these fields.

Regards
Brajesh

Answer (score 0):

You have to write drop-down change event in that u check for index or check for value according to that index/value you will do what u want. Means you can show as per your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Assign a class `non-mandatory` to each of the non-mandatory fields. Then attach an event handler to a button to toggle whether the non-mandatory fields are shown:

```
$('#myButton').on('click', function() {
    $('.non-mandatory').toggle();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to hide just the input elements/controls or the entire table row?  In either case you could apply a css class to the corresponding DOM elements and then bind the onchange event of the dropdownlist to handle the hiding and showing based on the selected value.

So in the case you want to hide the entire table row, for each tr you could apply a css class of either "mandatory" and "nonMandatory" then in your javascript you could do the following:

```
$('#myDropdownlist').con('change', function() {
    if ($(this).val() === 'mandatory') {
        $('.nonMandatory').hide();
        $('.mandatory').show();
    } else {
        $('.nonMandatory').show();
        $('.mandatory').hide();            
    }
});
```

Hope that helps